# ¿Hay alguna palabra para designar el acto de beber una botella o un recipiente entero de algún líquido?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

<sub>Leyendo la pregunta [What do you call the act of drinking a whole bottle of, say, water in one go?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/176128/3462) me ha surgido la duda para nuestro idioma...</sub>

¿Existe alguna palabra o expresión para designar el hecho de beber todo el contenido de un recipiente de golpe?

Por ejemplo:

- beberse todo el agua del vaso,
- ingerir todo el contenido de una petaca,
- beber de un tirón una bota de vino.

*Tomar de un trago* parece la traducción más directa de [*chugging*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=chugging), la palabra que más gente respalda para definir el concepto en inglés.

Son más que bienvenidas las expresiones regionales para designar este mismo concepto.

Comment: en español popular mexicano diríamos "de chingo la botella entera"

Comment: Existen frases, pero una sola palabra no la hay, y dichas frases son muy coloquiales, en Colombia se dice **Fondo Blanco** cuando uno se toma el contenido de una botella sin detenerse. Pero una palabra como tal no existe.

Comment: En Madrid, cuando hacíamos botellón y quedaba poco en una botella o vaso decíamos "mátalo", con el sentido de termínatelo entero.

Comment: En catalán decimos _fer un Sant Hilari_, pues se dice _Sant Hilari, Sant Hilari, fill de puta qui no s'ho acabi_ (es decir, _San Hilario, San Hilario, hijueputa quien no se lo acabe_, con Hilario y acabe rimando)

Comment: Simplemente, terminar?

Comment: @fedorqui yo he visto a gente hacer lo mismo con "hidalgo". Alguien dice "hidalgo (_hijoputa_ el que deje algo)" y todos a terminarse la bebida que tuviesen. Por cierto, el DRAE incluye [tragantada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aExQ9p7) como `Mayor trago que se puede tragar de una vez.`

Comment: Working on the basis of directly translating what I would say in English, what about _drenar_?

Comment: And note that in the UK a chugger is a person who approaches you in the street to try to get you to sign up to regular donations to a charity. Short for charity mugger (where a mugger is a street robber).

Comment: En Colombia decimos "se sampó toda la botella"

Comment: En Chile decimos "se tomó la botella **al seco**".

Comment: Se zampó la botella, dice mi sevillano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viendo que cada región tiene sus propias variantes y que difícilmente encontraremos uno válido para todas las zonas, añado esta respuesta en modo Community Wiki para que entre todos añadamos las versiones que conozcamos.

### Chile

- Tomarse la botella al seco.
- Tomarse la botella/el vaso de un pencazo/de una.

### Colombia / Argentina

- Fondo blanco: tomarse el contenido de una botella sin detenerse.
- Zamparse la botella.

### España

- Matar, para indicar el acto de terminar entero el contenido restante de una botella o un vaso.
- Beber de un trago
- *Hacer un hidalgo*, que tiene su origen en el reto *¡Hidalgo! ¡Hidalgo! ¡Hijo puta el que deje algo!*

#### Andalucía oriental

- *Beber a opla*

### México

- Chingarse la botella entera [vulgar]
- Tomarselo todo de un jalón
- Tomarse el trago o la botella **de Hidalgo**
- Fondo, Fondo

Comment: Añadí más opciones para Chile.

Comment: @Ustanak genial, gracias. Qué bueno verte de nuevo por aquí. Entiendo que [_pencazo_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pencazo) es sinónimo de _golpe_ en Chile.

Comment: Sí; también posee ese significado. Lo puedes usar cuando se trata de tomarse un trago rápidamente; de todas formas, no sé si use en otros países, por lo que imagino que su uso es netamente un chilenismo.

Comment: Agregue "De Hidalgo" y fondo fondo en México

Answer (score 1):

No sé si existe el verbo exacto que quieres. Pero si necesitas usar una única palabra, puedes decir “**vaciar** la botella” y dejar que el contexto deje claro que se vacía bebiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Beber "a opla" es una expresión que indica bebérselo todo de un trago. La expresión y la palabra no aparecen recogidas en la RAE, pero se usan en Andalucía oriental.

Comment: ¿dónde se usa? ¿desde cuándo? Puedes añadirla a la respuesta comunitaria

Comment: Andalucía oriental.

Answer (score 0):

En Galicia se utiliza mucho la expresión "**beber de penalti**".

Comment: Puedes añadirla a la respuesta comunitaria